# How can I represent integer infinity in Z3?

Tags: z3

I need to be able to compare two integer expressions, which may include literal integers, addition, unary negation, integer constants, and infinity, and decide if an inequality between them is satisfiable. This is part of a larger program, so there is no way for me to know ahead of time what those expressions will look like.

I have considered defining an integer constant and just letting it take any value, but then I realized that Infinity < 5 would be satisfiable.

I have considered defining a constant and making a universally quantified assertion that it is greater than all integers, but I don't know what Sort I should say it is. If I tell Z3 that the Sort of my Infinity constant is integer, I think it will probably happily go off and try to find me THE LARGEST INTEGER! I'm pretty sure that won't end the way I want.

Comment: This extension of Z3 allows infinitesimals: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/files/rcf.pdf. It mentions an implementation, but I don't know its current status.

Comment: Infinitesimals are values approaching zero (very small values). Infinity is not an infinitesimal. Nor is it a transcendental constant (which the paper you mentioned also discusses). So it doesn't seem like this gives me what I want.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I somehow believed that the extension discussed in the paper included infinity as well. BTW, your second suggestion should yield a contradiction: stating that, for some int N, N is larger than all ints, would imply that N > N. Stating that N is larger than all *other* ints would also yield a contradiction, namely, that N > M, where M = N+1.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely why I don't think it will work -- if I tell Z3 the infinity I want is itself an integer. I thought about telling Z3 that infinity is something else (some other Sort), but I've never done that before, so I don't know how to do it right. Moreover, I don't know if it will work or do what I want, and I was hoping someone would either say, "Sure, do that and here's how." or, "No, that's a waste of time, do this instead."

Answer (score 0):

I would create a composite type consisting of an integer and a boolean that says whether this particular value is infinity or not. Then, you need to define arithmetic on this. For example, if one of the operands is infinity then the result of an addition is infinity as well. Otherwise, it's the actual sum of the integers. Comparisons would be defined in a similar way (case based).

There is no need to actually create a type in the Z3 system. Just always create values in int/bool pairs in your code. A few helper functions can do that.

Doing this you will probably create a harder problem for Z3 to solve and maybe even escalate the logic you are using.